# Запуск программы в правом углу C#

Tags: c#, winforms

мне необходимо что бы программа(то есть форма) при запуске сразу находилась в правом верхнем углу

Comment: Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста тип вашей программы, это консольная программа или оконное приложение?

Comment: вроде у формы было свойство `anchor` - `top - right`... но это не точно )

Comment: Оконное приложение

Comment: Вопрос решен,всем спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        foreach (var scrn in Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            if (scrn.Bounds.Contains(Location))
            {
                Location = new Point(scrn.Bounds.Right - Width, scrn.Bounds.Top);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```